# Where do most development teams compile and run their code to test it?

Tags: software, team

Context: I'm not employed as a software developer. But I do hobby projects pretty regularly, and I was curious if application dependencies can be super varied during compilation and testing (if all developers are compiling their code locally) between 2 or 3 developers. Unless there is a cloud-hosted solution that has a common set of libraries, all on the same version, where testing and compilation regularly happens?

Edit Feb 5th 2023 8PM Chicago Time: These answers were very helpful. In many cases (not saying that's the majority), it seems like central servers (physical, VM, or container) are used to create consistency for developers. But other times the testing could be done locally if it's an established programming language/ecosystem. Thanks again those who answered!

Comment: normally you have a build machine that compiles/tests etc when you check in. These days its likely in the cloud

Comment: Typical deployment will be in a container. So working in a cloud-based or local [dev container](https://containers.dev) is a natural choice. Everyone builds the set of dependent libraries from scratch in the same way, using checked-in config files. "Everyone" is developers, testers, CI, and especially CD.

Comment: Containers made it a lot easier to set up a common build + test environment, otherwise VMs are useful. But ultimately, development tends to happen locally, with full testing tending to happen on central servers. This also depends massively on programming language. E.g. Python has good tooling to set up controlled environments with exact versions for dependencies, C++ not so much.

Comment: Assuming you're using any of the popular/well-known ecosystems (e.g.  .NET, Java, JavaScript, Python, etc) there should be no reason for library versions to vary between developers since those languages/ecosystems use package managers and reference library versions at the project level (the files which control package versions  for those tools are checked in along with the rest of the source code)

Comment: There are hundred thousands of development teams for all kind of software (desktop, web, embedded, for small inhouse development, project specific solutions or or large off-the-shelve products) all over the world. These teams hundreds of different programming ecosystems. For each of these types, there are all kind of development organizations, from single-developer teams up to multi-teams setups with several hundred developers involved. There is nothing like a clear "most popular" process for compiling and testing.

Comment: @J_H "typical" is pulling a lot of weight in that statement. Not everyone makes web apps you know.

Comment: @J_H: what in your environment is "typical", is not typical for others. I am developing software for four decades, and never used container deployment by myself in that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was curious if application dependencies can be super varied during compilation and testing (if all developers are compiling their code locally) between 2 or 3 developers. Unless there is a cloud-hosted solution that has a common set of libraries, all on the same version, where testing and compilation regularly happens?

People put in a *lot* of effort in many different software ecosystems to either eliminate such variance or make it manageable. Python "venv", npm's "package.json", nuget for C#, and so on.

Generally you'll want to be able to run the program (or subsystem) locally, *and* have a CI system that automatically runs tests for you before and after merges. The "integration" of CI.